# What is the correct way to recv non blocking socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, nonblocking, epoll

I have read lots of articles and Q&As, but I still have lost of troubles..
The socket is ET, non-blocking, and I used epoll, and now I want to recv some data on it.
The code are below my questions.(Is correct I guess?)

My questions are:

How can I know whether I have received all the data? When I run this server, each time the while loop break with `EAGAIN`. I found some people say that "EAGAIN means there is **no data available** for reading on a non-blocking socket". Well that make sense.

But is that equals to "Server have received all data from client when `EAGIAN`?" A neg example is maybe the socket buffer is full, and this time we get `EAGAIN`, but in fact the client still have some words to send to. Can this be possible ?

And can I add this lines `else if (nread < BUFF_SIZE) break;` ? Can I say if the nread smaller than BUFF_SIZE, I have already received all data?

Help me plz T_T

```
string read_buf;
char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
while (true) {
    int nread = recv(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE, 0);
    if (nread < 0) {
        if (errno == EINTR) continue;
        else if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            perror("read error");
            return -1;
        }
    } 
    else if (nread == 0) {
        close(fd);
        break;
    }
    read_buf += std::string(buff, buff + nread);
}
```

Comment: Define 'all the data'. TCP doesn't have messages. Only your application protocol may have those.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Application protocol is HTTP. the data are http header, body.. Is it the defination?

Comment: Certainly, so you have to pay attention to the Content-length header, or the Transfer-encoding header, or the `Connection: close` header, if any of these are present, according to the semantics of HTTP. You can't write an HTTP server of any description without actually implementing the protocol correctly, and it's a big job. Read the RFCs.